# The name 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

After training inception model. at time of inference I am getting this error.(i am using https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining )

> TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name
>   'DecodeJpeg/contents:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The
>   operation, 'DecodeJpeg/contents', does not exist in the graph.

```
omer@omer-HP-EliteBook-8540w:~/Downloads/tensorflow-
master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining$ python label_image.py --graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb --labels=/tmp/output_labels.txt --image=/home/omer/Downloads/tensorflow-master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/pwd/glass/glass52.jpg --output_layer=final_result


2017-08-13 17:10:05.642446: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-13 17:10:05.642507: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "retraining-example.py", line 86, in <module>
run_inference_on_image()
  File "retraining-example.py", line 69, in run_inference_on_image
{'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
  File "/home/omer/installed/acaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "/home/omer/installed/acaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 933, in _run
+ e.args[0])

TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 
'DecodeJpeg/contents:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The 
operation, 'DecodeJpeg/contents', does not exist in the graph.
```

Please Help, I am new to this subject

Comment: Are you using native pip or Anaconda to install TensorFlow?

Comment: i'm using anaconda

Comment: Are you using version 4.4 for Python 3.6?

Comment: using python 2.7 and conda 4.3.22

Answer (score 2):

Google has updated their `retrain.py` in `image_retraining`. They removed the `op:DecodeJpeg`, so you can't get it.